# Fill and read array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

What I actually do is getting a json string from the github api by calling

```
curl -u <userName> https://api.github.com/orgs/<orgName>/repos > test
```

I don't do it directly because in order to get jq to work, I've got to add  `{"result":` at the beginning and `}` at the end of the file manually.

Now to my script in *getthem*

```
RESULT=$(cat test | jq ".result[] | .html_url");
COUNT=0
URLS=()

for line in $RESULT;
do
  echo $COUNT $line
  URLS[$COUNT]=$line
  COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
done

#DEBUG
echo $URLS

COUNT=0
for url in $URLS;
do
  #DEBUG
  echo $COUNT $url

  #DO SOMETHING WITH RESULTS LATER
  # clone --bare $url $<onlyRepoName>.git

  COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
done
```

**My Problem:**
When I call `bash ./getthem` the first loop seems to work, but in the echos marked with #DEBUG there is only one line added to the array.

Here the output I get

```
0 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName0>"
1 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName1>"
2 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName2>"
3 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName3>"
4 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName4>"
5 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName5>"
6 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName6>"
7 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<RepoName7>"

"https://github.com/<orgName>/<repoName0>" #this should be the whole array

0 "https://github.com/<orgName>/<repoName0>" #here again it should be all 8 entries...
```

**What am I doing wrong? Why aren't all 8 entries in the URLS array?**

Comment: `./getthem: Line 8: Syntaxerror at unexpected word »(«
./getthem: Line 8:  URLS += ($line)'
`

Comment: Have it: without spaces! `URLS+=($line)` ... leads to the same output as in my question though

Comment: did it .. now my output is only the first 8 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access all elements in the `URLS` array, you need to use `${URLS[@]}` as below.

```
echo "${URLS[@]}"

COUNT=0
for url in "${URLS[@]}"
do
    # ...
done
```

[Reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html)

Comment: great this one did it!
I guess it was something about the pointer vs value thing?

Comment: Multiple ways in which this answer can be improved. 1) useless use of `cat` 2) avoiding anti-pattern to dump file into variable (should be using input redirection on the file) 3) unquoted variable expansion (`for line in $RESULT` word-splitting could happen) 4) unquoted array expansion( `for url in ${URLS[@]}`, word-splitting again) 5) general practice to double-quote variables